# ionic capacitor call typescript method from swift

Tags: swift, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an ionic capacitor app which has a custom native plugin. Calling the native code from TypeScript works fine, my swift code is called and the promise is returned. However I would also like the swift code to be able to call a couple of TypeScript methods (mainly to do http calls) but can't figure out how to.

From some reading I've found:

```swift
let script = "window.MyService.typescriptMethod();";
            self.bridge!.webView!.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error calling TypeScript method: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    if let resultString = result as? String {
                        print(resultString)
                    } else {
                        print("Unexpected result from TypeScript method")
                    }
                }
            })
```

However it is unable to find `MyService` as it's undefined. `MyService` is defined on the ionic side and is callable from there. So I'm not sure how to reference it from within swift, can anyone suggest how?